# Filtering a product list with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

First of all, I am quite "new" to php/mysql. I know some basic stuff and am following a course at Udemy right now. (Tips always welcome)

I have the following issue:

- I would like to generate an Article list from multiple Tables:

The List should contain our Article Number and the EAN and should only include Articles that are not already Listed in the SupplierData Table (So it will only contain Articles with missing Supplier info)

Table 1 ( ArticleDB)

| Artnr | Ean | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | row | 1,99 |
| 1001 | row | 2,99 |
| 1002 | row | 2,99 |
| 2000 | row | 2,99 |
| 3000 | row | 2,99 |

Table 2 (SupplierData)

| Artnr | SupplierID | SupplierArtnr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 70 | row |
| 1000 | 60 | row |
| 1002 | 60 | row |
| 1002 | 70 | row |
| 1001 | 81 | row |

What I tried for now:

`SELECT  a.artnr, a.ean`
`FROM    ArticleDB AS a`
`JOIN    SupplierData AS b ON a.artnr = b.artnr`
`WHERE   a.artnr NOT IN` 
        `(`
            `SELECT  Artnr`
            `FROM    SupplierData`
            `WHERE   SupplierID = 70`
        `);`

But it keept giving me a list with Data from other Suppliers. While i would like it ti only give out Numbers + EAN that are in ArtibleDB and do not yet have an entry in SupplierData for SupplierID 70

Example I was trying to get:

| Artnr | Ean |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | row |
| 2000 | row |
| 3000 | row |

Am I missing something? Or does someone have an other idea how to make this work?

Kind regards,
Stan

Comment: Why does 1000 appear in your desired output when there is a supplier 70

Comment: You are right, it should not be in. Removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer (While testing and trying):

```
SELECT  a.artnr, a.ean
FROM    ArticleDB AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN    SupplierDATA AS b ON a.artnr = b.artnr
WHERE   a.group != '---'
AND    a.group != 'TEC' 
AND    a.group != 'SER' 
AND a.artnr NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  Artnr
            FROM    SupplierData
            WHERE   SupplierID = 70
        )
      GROUP BY artnr
      ORDER BY artnr ASC;
```

Seems I had to force it to Group by artnr